# debugging javascript using source maps in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Is there a way to make visual studio load source maps when debugging javascript files?
in case we are debugging typescript in visual studio source maps are loaded but when debugging regular javascript files that has source maps then the source maps are ignored by the visual studio debuggers.
IE loads source maps and everything works.